# twitter bootstrap carousel customize with numbers instead of arrows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

This is my first post and I'm trying to learn rails with twitter bootstrap. I am using the carousel and I want the bottom right to contain numbers that are clickable to change the picture, rather than having arrows on the far left & right side of the image. For example, the numbers 1,2, & 3 could be in squares at the bottom right and each change the image shown. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

There is a plan to add pills navigation to the Carousel Plugin in milestone 2.3. There already exists [a pull request which adds that functionality](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4222), so you might be best off using that version of **[bootstrap-carousel.js](https://github.com/mikaelbr/bootstrap/blob/ff0b9ef165e830b34c52f9bb029ff407b892cf2d/js/bootstrap-carousel.js)**. However, be forewarned that this is new code and may be subject to changes, so if you elect to use it, be prepared to follow it through the life cycle.

Here is a demo of the updated plugin:

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/TycXE/)

Currently it uses pills, but changing it to numbers shouldn't be too difficult.  Probably just add some code like:

```
$('.carousel-pills > span').each(function (i) {
  $(this).text(i+1);
});
```

running this after the carousel initializes.  You'll have to tweak the LESS/CSS to change the pills from dots to boxes.